# yamaha のルーターの設定コマンドにおける、 pp は何を表す?

Tags: network

yamaha のルーター (rtx1210) の設定をしようとしています。

[コマンドリファレンス](http://www.rtpro.yamaha.co.jp/RT/manual/rt-common/index.html)を眺めていると、 `pp` という指示語が頻繁に登場しているな、と思っています。例: `pp select N`, `ip pp address 123.45.67.89/32`

## 質問

yamaha のルーターにおいて、 `pp` とは何を表す指示語なのでしょうか?

Comment: [RTX/RTシリーズ 取扱説明書](http://www.rtpro.yamaha.co.jp/RT/manual/Rev.9.00.01/Users.pdf)の「1.3 本文中で使用する用語について」に、「PP とは Point to Point の略。」と記載されています。

Comment: コメント欄は回答欄ではないです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"**P**oint-to-**P**oint" の略で "PP" ではないでしょうか。

[VPNプロトコルの概要 - PPTPとL2TP | マイナビニュース](https://news.mynavi.jp/article/vpn-4/)

参照しているマニュアル中には [PP インタフェース](http://www.rtpro.yamaha.co.jp/RT/manual/rt-common/http_server/pp_name.html) という単語も出てきます。